# Add permanant pronunciation to text to speech dictionary

Tags: text-to-speech

Is there any way to add a permanent pronunciation to OSX text to speech dictionary?

For example: I would like the word 'mkdir' to be read as 'make directory' each and every time I use the "Start Speaking" service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution so I wrote an automator script that does the job: [Custom Text To Speech](https://github.com/HarrisonQT/custom-text-to-speech)